# Canonical correlation and prediction

Tags: r, predictive-models, cross-correlation, canonical-correlation

Is it possible to predict values of variables in a matrix Y from values of variables in a matrix X, ie. using canonical correlations since some variables are correlated among these two matrix?

X and Y contain variables for the same individuals.

If possible, I would like an example using R.

Edit: the aim is to fill missing values in the matrix Y from correlated variables that are in matrix X.

Comment: Is this related to one of your [earlier question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13909/cross-matrix-inference-and-correlations)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use canonical correlation? Where does your data come from? Maybe canonical correlation isn't the best way to proceed: *the aim is to fill missing values in the matrix Y from correlated variables that are in matrix X*

Comment: Maybe another technique will be more adequate. My data are datas collected from user using a service that I provide.
I want to use data collected from users (values of variables in matrix X) to fill missing values about them for the variables that are in matrix Y.

Comment: @chl. absolutely